# How to prevent multiple event execution if there are multiple event handler methods for the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript, I have multiple event handler method decelerations for the same class. Is it possible to execute event handler method only once.

Please at look this:

```
<html>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".abc").click(function(){
                alert("clicked 1");
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $(".abc").click(function(){
                alert("clicked 2");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
       <input type="button" class="abc" value="click"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click on button I am getting two alert messages. but I want to get any one alert only.

Note : Buttons are getting dynamically. so, to associate event handler with the button I am call a method which will do like my script code.

Comment: Why are you binding two click events in the first place ?

Comment: Maybe what he wants is a better way to override event handler, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063564/how-to-override-a-previously-set-jquery-event-handler

Comment: Please clarify your need here what is the purpose to attach different event handler for same element

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).click(function(e)
{
   alert(e.target.id);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```