# Prevent interpretation of onMouseDown to disable the blocking of text selection

Tags: javascript, onmousedown

To my knowledge the most common way to prevent text selection/copy/paste is to specify your own empty onMouseDown function.

Now from a user perspective, what options do I have (using Firefox or Chrome) to prevent the execution of this other function.

Disabling javascript is not an option in this case, I have to disable just the text selection blocker.
Unfortunately I could not find it anywhere in the nested sources of the page.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063564/how-to-override-a-previously-set-jquery-event-handler